# How can I logoff from remote desktop in C#?

Tags: c#, rdp

I made a program with C# using AxInterop.MSTSCLib ActiveX COM Component to connect to a remote machine, this Activex doesn't have a logoff method and when I disconnect from the machine, the session is still alive. I found the WTSDisconnectSession function for disconnecting from a session but it needs a session Id, how can I get session Id in C#?

```
AxMSTSCLib.AxMsRdpClient6NotSafeForScripting rdp = new AxMSTSCLib.AxMsRdpClient6NotSafeForScripting();
rdp.Server = "127.0.0.1";
rdp.UserName = "user"
rdp.AdvancedSettings2.ClearTextPassword = "password";
rdp.Connect();

if (rdp.Connected.ToString() == "1")
{
    rdp.Disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Get Session ID from the Process List.  You can use from cmd.exe >wmic Process Name

Comment: The framework is .Net 3.5

Comment: It is a windows command that you need to run from Process Class.